# RecyclerView does not load images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made a simple RecyclerView, but it do not load images!
Here are my codes. RecyclerView has 11 raws and each raw has 2 textviews and 1 imageview,
This is the important part of main activity,
MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

String[] F_Name, D_Name;
int[] Img_res = {R.drawable.a_beautiful_mind,
                 R.drawable.a_seperation,
                 R.drawable.casablanca,
                 R.drawable.daei_jan_napelon,
                 R.drawable.game_of_thrones,
                 R.drawable.life_of_pie,
                 R.drawable.the_dictator,
                 R.drawable.the_godfather,
                 R.drawable.the_martian,
                 R.drawable.the_revenant,
                 R.drawable.v_for_vendetta};

ArrayList<DataProvider> arrayList = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    F_Name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Film_Names);
    D_Name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Director_Names);

    int i = 0;

    for (String name : F_Name){
        DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(Img_res[i], name, D_Name[i]);
        arrayList.add(dataProvider);
        i++;
    }

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Here is my Adapter, I added 11 raws, and each raw contains 2 textviews and 1 ImageView,
Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<DataProvider> arrayList = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<DataProvider> arrayList){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}


@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_recyclerview_raws, parent, false);

    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DataProvider dataProvider = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(dataProvider.getImg_res());
    holder.f_name.setText(dataProvider.getF_name());
    holder.d_name.setText(dataProvider.getD_name());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView f_name, d_name;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerViewImage);
        f_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myTextVFilmName);
        d_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.myTextVDirectorName);
    }

}
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you provide your `RecyclerAdapter` class please?

Comment: You should post your Adapter code

Comment: Will also need the layout xml.